# How to run a command in xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to track page views using Google Analytics in my iPhone application. I have a problem `_objc_class_$gantracker` seems to be undefined . I saw on a forum that the problem can be solved by running `lipo libGoogleAnalytics.a -remove i386 -output libGoogleAnalytics2.a`

Where I can write this in xcode ? How I get to write a command line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this in Project>Targets>Build Settings>Header search Paths .Just edit the value of that column with the libGoogleAnalytics sdk path.

Answer (score 0):

You don't run this code in XCode, but simply in the standard OS X command line. See also this [article](http://osxdaily.com/2006/11/22/ten-os-x-command-line-utilities-you-might-not-know-about/) (7.)